# static array buffer assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, buffer

Let's say I have defined an array `float floatBuffer[4]` and I have a struct: `struct vec3{float x,y,z;} myVec;`

before the vec3 assignment, I assign: `floatBuffer[3] = 0.0f;`

(If this is possible,) In what ways can I assign `myVec` to `floatBuffer[0]` (binary copy), so that

- floatBuffer[0] == myVec.x
- floatBuffer[1] == myVec.y
- floatBuffer[2] == myVec.z
- floatBuffer[3] == 0.0f

  ?

Comment: Since `floatbuffer` is static (I assume this from your title) all array elements will be zero-initialized unless you provide them with other non-zero compile time constants. You can of course modify them later on. Is your problem specifying the initial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is:

```
floatBuffer[0] = myVec.x;
floatBuffer[1] = myVec.y;
floatBuffer[2] = myVec.z;
```

If you're willing to make assumptions on struct layout, and *your compiler generates crappy code for the direct assignments*, document your assumptions and do a `memcpy`:

```
static_assert(sizeof(myVec) == sizeof(float[3]), "myVec should not have padding");

memcpy(&floatBuffer[0], &myVec, sizeof(myVec));
```

Comment: And if he has control over the declaration, he can do `float floatBuffer[4] = { myVec.x, myVec.y, myVec.z };`

Comment: I should have stated: in one go. Lol ;)

Comment: @xcrypt if you put that in a function and then call that function does it count as "in one go"? (It does to me)

Comment: I mean some kind of binary copy. Like memcpy() does. I'm wondering if there are additional ways

Comment: This is a binary copy (because `float` is a trivially copyable type).

Comment: just literally copying the data `(vec3*)&myVec` points to, to `floatBuffer`(interpreted as pointer) then. I thought that was called a binary copy?

Comment: *This is just literally copying the data*. There is no difference between the two, other than the fact that doing it with the pointers like you suggest relies on the compiler laying out the struct in a certain way.

Comment: @xcrypt `auto end = src+size; while(src != end) *dst++ = *src++;`

Comment: But I thought you can't increment a void*. Or would it be casted to char* ? Why can't it just pick all the bytes and copy them instead of doing an iteration?

Comment: @xcrypt oh, right, I forgot that. It can't "just pick all the bytes and copy them" because computers aren't magical. That said, that doesn't mean the resulting assembly will have a loop at all. I suspect the assignments and the memcpy will result in very similar generated code.

Comment: and why would that be magical? all the parameters needed are known, start location, number of bytes to copy, the bytes themselves.

Comment: @xcrypt: because computers can't magically move lots of bytes at once.  They have to loop.  That's how copies work with more than one variable.

Comment: @MooingDuck and what is the reason for computers not being able to copy a lot of bytes at once? "Because they have to loop" doesn't make any sense to me. They can copy multiple bits at once, so why not multiple bytes?

Comment: @xcrypt Oh, they can copy "multiple bytes" at once, but only a *limited* number of them. Because ultimately the hardware down below has a limit on the number of bytes that can be transferred at once. Buses don't have infinite bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I really wanted to know :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard does say that there may be padding even within (but not at the beginning) of a *standard-layout-struct*, so a binary copy may not be portable. However, given a particular system and packing instructions (lookup `#pragma pack`) you may just be able to use `memcpy`.

You can try the following:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

// look up your compiler's documentation
//#pragma pack(4) 

struct fs {
 float x, y, z;
};

int main() {
 fs b = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
 float p[ 4 ] = {0};
 static_assert( sizeof b == sizeof p - 1, "warning: padding detected!" );
 std::memcpy(&p[ 0 ], &b, sizeof p - 1);
 std::copy(&p[ 0 ], &p[ 0 ] + 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use memcpy, however as mentioned memcpy can be fragile depending on packing.

I think the best solution here is to use multiple statements and not to to be tricky.

```
floatBuffer[0] = myVec.x; 
floatBuffer[1] = myVec.y; 
floatBuffer[2] = myVec.z;
```

By doing it the obvious way... 
the code is clear on what's going on and you can let the compiler optimize the code for you.

One question that does come to mind, 
is why are you using a float array rather than either a vec3 or vec3 array (which would allow a single assignment)

Comment: Because I want the floatbuffer to be able to represent anything. For example representing a vertex in a DirectX vertex buffer

Comment: You might consider a union of types you will be working with.

Answer (score 1):

You could make up a function for this.

```
struct vec3{float x,y,z;} myVec;

float* operator<< (float t[4], vec3 v) {
  t[0] = v.x; t[1] = v.y; t[2] = v.z; t[3] = 0;
  return t;
}

int main() {
  float test[4];
  test << myVec; // now do the assignment 'in one go'
  return 0;
}
```